# Go func with generics and parameters

Tags: go

I am new to Golang and come from nodejs development. in typescript it is possible to use generic in function while passing other parameters as well but I wonder if i can accomplish similar thing with Golang.

For example in typescript one can use

```
  private async request<T>(query: string, variables: object): Promise<T> {....}
```

I am trying similar thing in golang with no success. What I have right now is

```golang
type Mwapp struct {
    Debug     bool            `json:"debug"`
    Context   context.Context `json:"-"`
    Client    graphql.Client  `json:"-"`
}

type Handler[T any] struct {
    caller        func(ctx context.Context, client graphql.Client) (*T, error)
    operationName string
}

//i WANT TO USE GENERICS IN THIS FUNCTION SO THAT I CAN REUSE IT MULTIPLE TIMES
func (mwapp *Mwapp) request[PASS_HERE_GENERIC](handler Handler[T]) (*T, error) {
    res, err := handler.caller(mwapp.Context, mwapp.Client)

    return res, err
}

func (mwapp *Mwapp) GetMyAccount() (*myAccountResponse, error) {
    return mwapp.request(Handler[myAccountResponse]{myAccount, "GetMyAccount"})
}

func (mwapp *Mwapp) GetMyApp() (*myMwappResponse, error) {
    return mwapp.request(Handler[myMwappResponse]{myApp, "GetMyApp"})
}
```

Any help to accomplish this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is declared, `request` is a method of `*Mwapp`. The only way to make it a generic function is my making `Mwapp` generic. Another way of doing this is by declaring `request` as a function instead of a method. Then you can make it generic without making `Mwapp` a generic type:

```
func request[T](mwapp &Mwapp, handler Handler[T]) (*T, error) {
}
```